# Changed permalinks, messed up portfolio items

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I wanted to change all the blog posts on our corporate site from category/postname to /blog/postname, so all the blog posts would be in one folder. I reset the permalinks from /%category&/postname /blog/%postname%/

After publishing the first new post under this structure. I noticed that they had tons of case studies and resources set up as portfolio posts and so

/portfolio/case-study/

is now changed to:

/blog/portfolio/case-study/

How can I fix this so blog posts stay the new way I want them, but the portfolio goes back to the way it was?

Tried finding a way to set link types for just portfolio items, or change the URLs back manually, didn't work.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

So you'd want: /blog/%postname% and that will apply to blog and custom posts.

I'm guessing portfolio is a custom post type so in the CPT setup $args you'd need to add:   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio' )

Then flush permalinks/save permalinks again and it *should* work

Answer (score 0):

I think the eastest way is to create a category called "blog" in posts and assign posts under blog category, the portfolio will stay the way it was.